# best way to make buttons

Tags: java, android

I decided to completely switch my app around and made a navigation drawer. I made all of my fragments but now I need to include buttons in them. I have never put buttons in FrameLayouts before and was wondering if there was an easier way. below is the fragment_rewards.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="east.myapplication.RewardsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    </FrameLayout>
```

I want to include a few buttons like ...

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amazon"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/amazon"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/amazon"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

    <Button
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PlayStation"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/playstation"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/playstation"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:textSize="35sp"/>
```

Does anyone know of an easier way to include all of these buttons on my fragment_rewards.xml without using framelayout? Before when I put buttons on a page i was using LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, You dont need a Framlayout, You can use LinearLayout like I have done in the past.